# Function can't infer mapped type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a function with a set of predefined request/response based on an enum. However the type cannot be inferred by typescript, it only works if I specify the generic argument

here is [the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwHMQMAVARgB4T4QAPDEVYAZ3hIE8AHEAPgAo4ARwBc8AEohBZANokAugEpRE5rLkBuAFChIsBCnTY8hYiQBMVGvUYs2XXgMnLJFkjyXiQq+Vp3Q4SGiYuPhEpADMlnQMTKwc3PxCzoKRbh4qalqajMgAtnbc8ADemvBl8ACCADSl5QBCNeXwAMI1AL6amhj2nlLwALzFtWWy9gB0FXKiRfAwUKLMGDBYqARV8N3covEgE-BtjeWj3GN1U8WzAEYLSytrG-bb43X7hyM7Y83nMzBgN8urdabEBPE7NfaaDpdHoSQSuKwxWw7HgDIZNYHbN6zf53dqdYG9VIImxxewowawmQ+fEwryokpNY67SbTeDzeCLAEEV7DeBM07feDXDm3VY8xkfL6sv4irkQqFgPCLNms9mcu77VFhch8GYYgrM9ZzUQAchN+wU6ngAHprTQYDAcDB4ABaeAASXgAHcoKgMBsABZYZiaRWoZVQdkzNWi7ltLWmSgfCr8PWPA0TI3ss0Wq2271OgDWIdDSv9UDMqpxYvjg21Zl1Dy2Geq2PgObalptdq9RdYpfD5YrVdlGtrJlIrnGKcb+uTRtN5s7eZ7fc6YYj4RH6prCYis-T89m2aXXfzIAdToHEagW4uMbl4+1qWnqabIJbWcXue7BZgxaAA)

what I want is `a` or `a3` to work, but instead the return type is the union of all responses

```
declare function getT1<T extends Type>(req: Req1[T]): Res[T];
declare function getT2<T extends Type>(req: Req2<T>): Res[T];
declare function getT3<T extends Type>(req: Req3<T>): Res[T];

enum Type {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}

type Req1 = {
    [Type.A]: { ra: string, type: Type.A },
    [Type.B]: { rb: string, type: Type.B },
    [Type.C]: { rc: string, type: Type.C }
}

type Req2<T extends Type> = {
    type: T,
    r: string,
}

type Req3<T extends Type> = Req1[T];

type Res = {
    [Type.A]: { a: string },
    [Type.B]: { b: string },
    [Type.C]: { c: string }
}

const a: { a: string } = getT1({ type: Type.A, ra: '' }); // error - I want this
const aa: { a: string } = getT1<Type.A>({ type: Type.A, ra: '' }); // works

const a2: { a: string } = getT2({ type: Type.A, r: '' }); // works 
const aa2: { a: string } = getT2<Type.A>({ type: Type.A, r: '' }); // works

const a3: { a: string } = getT3({ type: Type.A, ra: '' }); // error
const aa3: { a: string } = getT3<Type.A>({ type: Type.A, ra: '' }); // works
```

Comment: got it, I put my solution as an answer instead, then should I create another post for the follow-up question?

Comment: Yes, if you have a followup question that you can't find the answer to then you should probably make a new post for it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwHMQMAVARgB4T4QAPDEVYAZ3hIE8AHEAPgAo4ARwBc8AEohBZANokAugEpRE5rLkBuAFChIsBCnTY8hYiQBMVGvUYs2XXgMnLJFkjyXiQq+Vp3Q4SGiYuPhEpADMlnQMTKwc3PxCzoKRbh4qar7g-vpBRqGmACxR1rF2CY4inoLFac7eGpqajMgAtuUIAN6a8L3wAIIAND19AELDffAAwsMAvk0Y9tVk8AC88N2TsvYAdP1yop3wMFCizBgwWKgEg-CL3KLxIHvwsxN929w7owcbxwBGZwuVxud3sj12o1e716n2eU1+RxgYCBl2ut3uIAhXymr00800mOqrisMVsTx4aw2I16mMeMOOqJBcwWSwkKRKZLi9kp63ZMh8rO41VqpJs3ISVM2fTpbHx8AAZGwALJQTiZIUIEiqzhSmnwOF7RHHU7wc5ogjQ-WGn6HAFM65WrZPHYIu3Ih2Wt74zWeVjraWwl37O2m80gp0fF22v6As3Ax3e527N1-FHxi14glgPDneCmo5hhNeqlhch8I6y4O3E6iADkddeCnU8AA9K2aDAYDgYPAALTwACS8AA7lBUBg7gALLDMTQ51B5qAF-Oe16l0yUYP8Svgjp7GumhtNlvt0c9gDWc-nucnUDMobXsw3pDMFbBD33Q0Z8GPs2bbYdiOl6sDei53vej4ZhGz7rGWri7P0O4fliX41vWjb-qeQEgU0C5LuEUHhomL4kOE75Vohh4YSegGdt2MBgUuUCEX8RaZrBJgRFQiHIZRXzfrWv6YQBZ7ATAV54be+aFERxbrnBRQUXu1YmjRWF0eJkn4RBslsU+pG1LxymfqpQl-qJOEScwQA)

basically don't put the type in the map:

```
declare function getT4<T extends Type>(req: Req4<T>): Res[T];

type Req4<T extends Type> = {
    type: T
} & TMap[T];

type TMap = {
    [Type.A]: { ra: string },
    [Type.B]: { rb: string },
    [Type.C]: { rc: string },
}

const a4: { a: string } = getT4({ type: Type.A, ra: '' }); // works
const aa4: { a: string } = getT4<Type.A>({ type: Type.A, ra: '' }); // works
```

however, if I wrap the whole thing in a `Readonly` then it stops working, individual readonly is ok

```
type Req4<T extends Type> = Readonly<{
    type: T
} & TMap[T]>; // nope

type Req4<T extends Type> = Readonly<{
    type: T
}> & TMap[T]; // ok
```

However I don't have enough knowledge of how it works under the hood